# How to show every result from awk rand() loop in separated files?

Tags: loops, awk

I'm trying to generate several files with random column, using awk. And then paste each two into one file with two columns. This will be an input to another program. The problem that I'm facing is that I get only the last iteration in one file.
The code I'm using is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
srand();
total=5;
max1=10;
count=0;
    while(count < total) {
    rnd1 = int(rand() * max1);
    if ( array[rnd1] == 0 ) {
        count++;
        array[rnd1]++;
    }
}

for ( i=0; i<=200; i++) {
    if ( array[i] )
        print i;
}
}' > out1

awk 'BEGIN {
srand();
total=5;
max2=20;
count=0;
    while(count < total) {
    rnd2 = int(rand() * max2);
    if ( array[rnd2] == 0 ) {
        count++;
        array[rnd2]++;
    }

}

for ( j=0; j<=max2; j++) {
    if ( array[j] )
        print j;
}
}' > out2

paste out1 out2 | awk '{ print "  "$1".0" , $2".0"; }' > out3
```

Is there a better way to get all the iterations in separate files ?

The output I'm getting is :

```
  1.0 2.0
  3.0 7.0
  4.0 9.0
  6.0 12.0
  9.0 13.0
```

which is fine, but it's in one file "out3", I want to get all the iteration files "out(i)" files.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your efforts in form of code, keep it up. Please do add sample of input and expected output in your question, for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have no input, just random numbers. I edited the question, I put an output form one of the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to file using `>` will erase the content of the file. Use `>>` instead, and follow the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) for further help.

> **print items >> output-file**
>
> This redirection prints the items into the preexisting output file
> named output-file. The difference between this and the single-‘>’
> redirection is that the old contents (if any) of output-file are not
> erased. Instead, the awk output is appended to the file. If
> output-file does not exist, then it is created.

For example:

```
for ( i=0; i<=200; i++) {
    if ( array[i] )
        print i;
}
}' > out1
```

will erase the content of `out1` at each iteration. Only the last iteration will be actually saved in `out1` without being over-written.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and for the link. Indeed this add the information on the file. The thing is I want to get it into a separate file. Thank you

Comment: your title is pretty explicit: how to fix _this_ problem. Please do not ask multiple questions in the same post.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that the The title was not explicit. Fixed it :)